# old facebook pages and graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

back in the old facebook when you clicked on a "like" button it created a page. I found one of them, randomly, and I could migrate it to the new page thing. The thing is, I had many more but no way of knowing where they are.

Is there a way to query the graph to know which old pages I can administrate?

Answer (score 1):

Graph API ([Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)) AFAIK, you can get all pages that you administrate so probably there are that wierd things.

Get access token with permission `manage_pages` and query `/me/accounts`

Comment: doesn't do the trick, only shows page I already have. Maybe because they haven't been migrated yet.